# How to use AutoExec macro to assign labels certain text on startup in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an AutoExec macro opening a form with lots of buttons and labels, etc. One of the labels will show the path directory to a folder. I have a button that lets you browse and choose a folder, and the label will be updated with the most recently selected folder path. As a default folder path. I want it to go to the individual user's

> C:\Users\exampleName

folder. As a test, I generated a message box displaying their home folder using the following function:

```
Public Function setPath()

    Dim defaultPath As String
    defaultPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
    pathLabel1.Caption = defaultPath

End Function
```

The issue is that in order to run code from an AutoExec macro, it can't be in the form module. But in order to access the label and its properties in order to update them, I have to be in a form module. I don't know how to get around this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just set the access modifiers on the labels to `Public` so you can access them?

Comment: How would I set that for a label? There isn't much documentation on it

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with Access VBA in over a decade.  I remember it's a lot different than VBA in other office products, so setting access on form members might not be the same.  I just don't remember.

Comment: Use the function to return the value, so setPath=defaultPath, then you can use from anywhere, something like `public function setPath() as string` then in the form, `me.label1.caption = setPath()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue is that in order to run code from an AutoExec macro, it cant
>   be in the form module. But in order to access the label and its
>   properties in order to update them, I have to be in a form module. I
>   don't know how to get around this.

Create a VBA function which performs two actions:

1. Open your form: `DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName"`
2. Change that label's `Caption`: `Forms![YourFormName]!pathLabel1.Caption = Environ$("USERPROFILE")`

Then change your AutoExec macro to call the function with the macro `RunCode` action.

But perhaps you would prefer to adjust the `Caption` every time the form opens, not just at database start.  In that case, set the `Caption` from the *Form Load* event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me!pathLabel1.Caption = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
End Sub
```